# Customizing LyX Shortcuts

Tags: lyx, keyboard

I am using LyX 2.0.6 on my macbook and would like to define a few custom shortcuts to make my life easier. In particular, I'd like to add the following command:

<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> should insert an algorithm float.

LyX is installed in `/Applications` and uses `/Applications/LyX/Contents/Resources/bin/mac.bind` as it's keyboard shortcuts config file
So I looked at the syntax in in there and came up with the following `custom.bind`:

```
# Command - C 
# Option  - A 
# Control - M 
# Shift   - S 

Format 1

\bind "C-S-r"                       "dialog-show-new-inset ref"
\bind "C-A-c"                       "citation insert"
\bind "C-A-t"                       "citation insert"
\bind "M-f ~S-a"                    "float-insert algorithm"
\bind "M-f ~S-f"                    "float-insert figure"
\bind "M-f ~S-t"                    "float-insert table"
```

Now, this custom.bind lives at `~/.config/LyX/custom.bind`, so I added the following line to my `mac.bind`:

```
\bind_file ~/.config/LyX/custom.bind
```

But I am unable to use the float command that I have defined in `custom.bind`. Thinking that this was an error in my syntax, I copied that line into `menus.bind` (and changed the bind file in LyX) and it did indeed work.

So why don't the commands in my custom.bind work?

Technical Specs:

- mac OSX 10.9.4 (Mavericks)
- LyX 2.0.6

Comment: So, just to be clear, this is a question about why your approach does not work, not how to customize shortcuts in general, right? Because for that you could also use the GUI interface available under `Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget did you try what Rasmus suggested? Also, consider updating your LyX installation (although make sure everything is backed up). 2.0.6 is now considered old.

Comment: @Rasmus: I have had trouble finding the right shortcut itself, in the GUI (Some are menu shortcuts that don't appear in `Tools > Preferences > ...` . Further, every time I update my installation, I would lose my custom shortcuts.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: When a function does not appear in the list, you can click `New` to add it if you know the function to call -- I just tried adding a shortcut with function `float-insert algorithm` from your Q, and that worked on LyX 2.1 (under Ubuntu). That your custom settings are overridden on update sounds like a bug -- at least that does not happen under Ubuntu.

Comment: @Rasmus: I tried editing the shortcuts in the preferences like you said - the changes didn't take. I updated to LyX 2.1.1. The new shortcuts were still there. Yet, they didn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Good that the shortcuts kept over update! What happens if you 1) Change to a different key combination? Try maybe `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + A`. Also try overriding one that works for something else. What happens? 2) Can you change an existing shortcut to something else, with effect? Does it work if you use your desired key combination? 3) Can you create a shortcut for a different function, say `math-insert \forall`?

Comment: Okay, so actually the specific key combination `Ctrl + f, a` does not work for me either, sorry that I didn't check that earlier. What keys is `dialog-show findreplace` assigned to on the Mac?

Comment: @Rasmus: `dialog-show findreplace` is mapped to `cmd+shift+f`. Remapping `float-insert algorithm` to `control+alt+shift a` makes it work. Mapping `math-insert \forall` to `control+alt+shift+m a` also works. I wonder why the `control+f` family of commands doesn't work. Thoughts?

Comment: That was why I asked for the shortcut for find - on Ubuntu, that's set to `Ctrl + f`. Try searching instead for `Ctrl + f` - is it assigned to something?

Comment: @Rasmus: `ctrl+f` is mapped to `char-forward`, which I never use. Deleting it and remapping `float-insert algorithm` to `ctrl+f a` got me exactly what I needed. If you consolidate the comments into an answer, I would gladly accept and give you the rep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how the custom `.bind` files work on Mac, so I can offer no insights about that.

However, seeing that the shortcut you want to define begins with `Ctrl + f`, your problem might have arisen due to a binding conflict. On Ubuntu, for example, `Ctrl + f` is by default bound to `dialog-show findreplace`. I've heard rumors that on Mac it is bound `char-forward` ;)

You can check whether the initial segment of your shortcut is already used by going to `Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts` and there search for `ctrl+f` (or whatever other shortcut you have problems getting to work).

If the initial segment is bound to something, then either choose a different shortcut, or remove the default binding.

Best of luck!